# Update Layer with python, error attribute renderer

Tags: python, arcmap, symbology

I am attempting to automate symbology using python, and ArcMap 10.0. I am importing this script into a toolbox, which I run from arcmap

Currently I am getting two errors:

1) LayerObject: Set attribute renderer does not exist. I am not sure what the problem is.

2) When I change true to false, Could not find replacement layer.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)[0]

sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\me\fun.lyr")


for lyr in updateLayer:

    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, updateLayer, sourceLayer, True)

#UpdateLayer ( data_frame, update_layer, source_layer, {symbology_only})
```

Answer (score 2):

Had help from a co-worker who solved the problem.

I was trying to update a list of layers instead of a single layer file in my for loop.

Here's the solution.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

updateLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df)

sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\me\fun.lyr")


for lyr in updateLayer:

    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, sourceLayer)
```